# rails each loop with from to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

In my controller i fetch 9 row's for object organizations.

```
  @organizations = Organization.where(parent_id: 1).order(city_id: :asc, is_vip: :desc, title: :asc).limit(25).sample(9)
```

and then in view i must separate this 9 value's to 3 view loops, like first .each do   if for row's 1-3, second for 4-6, third 6-9

and i try so:

```
- @organizations[0..2].each do |org|
...
- @organizations[3..5].each do |org|
...
- @organizations[6..8].each do |org|
...
```

but it seems that i do something wrong, but what exactly? and how to do it right?

Comment: Why do you say you're doing something wrong? What is the problem you're seeing?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi data is sometime's repeated

Comment: Are you sure there isn't duplicate data in the actual result set?

Comment: @Chuck check now - no, no duplicates

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why your data is duplicated. But you can use the following method for splitting the array into slices

you can use `each_slice`

```
@organization.each_slice(3) do |sliced_orgs|
end
```

Some documentation [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice)

Comment: is it right syntax to view? `%ul
          - @organizations[0..2].each do |org1|
            %li
              =link_to org1.title, organization_path(org1)
              %p
                =raw "<strong>#{org1.city.name}</strong>, <br> #{org1.address}"
      .introtext-separator
      .introtext
        %ul
          - @organizations[3..5].each do |org2|
            %li
              =link_to org2.title, organization_path(org2)
              %p
                =raw "<strong>#{org2.city.name}</strong>, <br> #{org2.address}"`

Answer (score 0):

First I don't really get why you use `.limit(25).sample(9)`, you could limit your results to 9 already. But maybe you have some use of the random factor introduced by sample? Strange.

Other than that,

```
@organizations[0..2].each do |org|
    puts org
end
...
```

should work perfectly fine. If the data is repeated it is because you have multiple times the same entry in your model. `sample(9)` is taking random unique entries and `@organizations[0..2]` is a fixed range returning an array or nil. (Rubydoc : `ary[range] → new_ary or nil`)

In short, nothing wrong with the code but probably somewhere in your data/logic.

Comment: I think OP wants to get nine random entries, not nine deterministic entries.

Comment: is it right syntax to view? `%ul
          - @organizations[0..2].each do |org1|
            %li
              =link_to org1.title, organization_path(org1)
              %p
                =raw "<strong>#{org1.city.name}</strong>, <br> #{org1.address}"
      .introtext-separator
      .introtext
        %ul
          - @organizations[3..5].each do |org2|
            %li
              =link_to org2.title, organization_path(org2)
              %p
                =raw "<strong>#{org2.city.name}</strong>, <br> #{org2.address}"`